# DirectX header error

Tags: c++, directx

today i wanted to start on a new project. (c++, Visual Studio 2015)
I created project, included DirectX SDK (in the same way as in my other projects) but I'm facing there this error: syntax error: identifier 'LPGLYPHMETRICSFLOAT' - in d3dx9shape.h, is there some way to fix/ignore the error?

I'm including dx like that:

```
#include <d3dx9.h>
#include <d3d9.h>
#pragma comment( lib, "d3dx9.lib" )
#pragma comment( lib, "d3d9.lib" )
```

I linked all needed stuff and i also tried to search but i haven't found any solution for this specific issue.

Comment: Include the header: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374209(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

With VS 2015, make sure you have your VC++ Directories set up correctly, which is the *reverse* of the traditional include order: First the Windows SDK, then the DirectX SDK. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275(v=vs.85).aspx) for details.

Second, make sure you are including `<windows.h>`. You need to be sure not to use `NOGDI`. Also, be sure to include `<d3d9.h>` before `<d3dx9.h>`.

> You should probably not be starting a new project using legacy Direct3D 9 anyhow. Use DirectX 11, and avoid using the legacy DirectX SDK and the `D3DX` utility library as well. See [Living without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/), [Direct3D Game VS Template](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates) and [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).